# WordPress BlogInfo() not working! What is going on?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

[ScreenShot of Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IpivF.png)

When I run this code

```html
<?php 
    function greet($name, $color) {
        
        echo "<p>Hi, my name is $name and my favorite color is $color.</p>";
    }
greet('John','blue');
greet('Jane', 'yellow');
?>

<h1><?php bloginfo('name'); ?></h1>
```

I am taking this from a tutorial. I followed it exactly. I am in the WordPress folder (wordpress/wp-content/themes/sitename/index.php

But I get a fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function bloginfo() in -file-.

Is seems like bloginfo() does not work in this context. Other coding languages you need to import or link the file where the function is found. In php, it seems you don't need to do that? It just "knowns" that bloginfo() is a function what wordpress has created...does not make sense. But I don't see any information on how to tell the file that bloginfo() has been created elsewhere.

Thanks for your help,

Chris

Answer (score 1):

This returns the same as the default blog_info('name') - [WordPress documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_bloginfo/).

`<?php $blog_title = get_bloginfo( 'name' ); echo $blog_title; ?>`

Answer (score 1):

WordPress Initialization: Before using WordPress-specific functions like get_bloginfo(), make sure that you've initialized WordPress by including the wp-blog-header.php file at the beginning of your PHP file. You can do this by adding the following line before the code you provided:

```
<?php require_once('wp-blog-header.php'); ?>
```

when I tried, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Chris I am doing the same tutorial and have the same problem I wondered if you managed to figure it out? It's difficult when you are learning with so many things going on like xxamp, MySQL, Wordpress, PHP in vs code I don't even know what questions to ask but eh maybe you came across something in the meantime, good luck with everything, hopefully not a too frustrating 2020 ;D

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is from quite some time ago, but you skipped the section on creating a theme or messed something up there. You have to create and activate the new theme and insert the bloginfo line into the index.php file of that new theme. You can't use the root file you created in the beginning or the default theme index.php.

Answer (score 0):

I tried in localhost and I could solve it.

Instead of writing the file path in the URL such as

http://localhost/test-plugin/wp-content/themes/fictional-university-theme/index.php

just write

http://localhost/test-plugin/

which "test-plugin" is the name of the folder in which the WordPress installed.

I hope this help.